# MaxExpansionDepth in odata is not returning the expected result

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, odata

I have added `MaxExpansionDepth` to my controller.
Calling `https://localhost:44392/odata/onderdelen?$expand=OnderdeelLocaties($expand=locatie(**$expand=bedrijf**))` is not adding the 
third level (`bedrijf`).

Using a similar controller and calling `https://localhost:44392/odata/locaties?$expand=bedrijf` is returning the expected result. This does confirm that my navigation properties are correct.

Controller :

```
[HttpGet]
[EnableQuery(MaxExpansionDepth = 8)]
public IActionResult Get(ODataQueryOptions<Onderdeel> options){

    return Ok(MockData());

}
```

Models :

```
public class Onderdeel
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Naam { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OnderdeelLocatie> OnderdeelLocaties { get; set; }

}

public class OnderdeelLocatie
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OnderdeelId { get; set; }
    public int LocatieId { get; set; }
    public virtual Onderdeel Onderdeel { get; set; }
    public virtual Locatie Locatie { get; set; }

}

public class Locatie
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Naam { get; set; }
    public int BedrijfId { get; set; }
    public virtual Bedrijf Bedrijf { get; set; }

}


public class Bedrijf
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Naam { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Locatie> Locaties { get; set; }

}
```

Returned result :

{"@odata.context":"https://localhost:44392/odata/$metadata#Onderdelen","value":[{"id":0,"naam":"OND","onderdeelLocaties":[{"id":0,"onderdeelId":0,"locatieId":0,"locatie":{"id":3,"naam":"TestLocatie","bedrijfId":4}}]}]}

Expected result :

{"@odata.context":"https://localhost:44392/odata/$metadata#Onderdelen","value":[{"id":0,"naam":"OND","onderdeelLocaties":[{"id":0,"onderdeelId":0,"locatieId":0,"locatie":{"id":3,"naam":"TestLocatie","bedrijfId":4, **bedrijf: { id : 3, naam : "bedrijf" }** }}]}]}

Answer (score 0):

Turns out i used `DefaultODataBatchHandler`

```
b.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", 
            "odata", 
            GetEdmModel(),
            new DefaultODataBatchHandler());
```

Removing the `DefaultODataBatchHandler` solved all issues with multiple levels. Including posting data to my odata api with more than 3 levels which resulted in invalid input.